# Problems with form and appendRow

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I created a form in Google Script and one of the fields is a Checkbox, the name of the field would be field1 []

and to save the answers in a sheet, I am using AppendRow, but when I insert the name of the field that has [], I get an error, and if I remove them the selections are not saved correctly.

This is my code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12CUQaajvhcQjcskDgA7YHc6EWdK67wq9LqBiauBoi4/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  ws.appendRow([
 
  formObject.field1]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. There are missing details, more specifically the Index.html file (add a minimal, complete and verifiable version).

Answer (score 1):

> `ws.appendRow([formObject.field1]);`

That looks fine, provided that the HTML form includes an input with that exact name, as in `<input name="field1">`.

> when I insert the name of the field that has `[]`

If you really have a form input field whose name attribute is something like `field1[]`, you should probably choose a different name. If you cannot change the name attribute for some reason, try this in your server-side code:

`ws.appendRow([formObject.['field1[]']]);`